# PHP POST method json_decode return NULL

Tags: php, json, extjs

I'm using sencha touch and I'm sending data to php REST server to save it to database, in firebug I can see the parameters that sencha touch send to php side, but in php I have this code:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$post_vars);
$info=$post_vars['customers'];
$data=json_decode(stripslashes($info),true);
```

The json_decode return NULL, the get_magic_quotes_gpc is off I also tried utf8_encode but always I got NULL, I tried var_dump and at the response I got extra text:

```
    array(1) {
     ["customers"]=>
     string(50) "{"c_name":"test","c_tel":"08-05852821","id":"112"}"
    }
```

I don't know how to continue, before the var_dump the post contains:

```
{"success":{"customers":"{\"c_name\":\"test\",\"c_tel\":\"08-05852821\",\"id\":\"112\"}"}}
```

I tried stripslashes but I got also NULL...

Any idea...

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($_POST);` or `var_dump($_GET)` if the method is GET? That probably gives you direct access to what you need.

Comment: I got this var_dump($_POST): array(1) {["customers"]=>string(50) "{"c_name":"test","c_tel":"08-05852821","id":"112"}"
}

Comment: how can I access "c_name"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I would access `$_POST` directly:

```
$info = json_decode($_POST['customers'], true);
echo $info['c_name'];
```

Comment: Works!!! but in all my searches in google I have seen the use of file_get_contents("php://input").

Comment: I really want to understand the problem and the solution, I was following a tutorial step by step doing php REST server side and they use file_get_contents("php://input") ?!

Comment: @user2005049 That's surprising, when you post a form - or key-value pairs using ajax - using the global variables of `$_POST` and `$_GET` is almost always the easiest way to access your data, see for example http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php.

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilities how Jason can be transmitted.

- First, it can be a get variable with a Name (`index.php?data={success:true}`), this only Works for Short json strings.
- Second, it can be a post variable with a Name ( will be Sent as `x-www-form-urlencoded`)
- Third, you can post only json (Store.sync does that)

Only the Latter will be accessed via `php://Input`, it Seems as of you use the Second.